# Sorting a 2D Char and Int Array from class using bubble sort?

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort an array of `int` and `char`s (from a class) by descending order. These are student names and grades.

The class is defined as:

```
class Student {
public:
    char name[20];
    int grades;
};
```

`numCount` is the incremental value of number of records.

```
void bubble_sort(Student theResults[], int numCount)
{
  bool swapped = true;
  while(swapped)
  {
    swapped = false;
    for(int i=1;i<numCount;i++)
    {
      if(theResults[i-1].grades < theResults[i].grades)
      {
        int tempHold = theResults[i-1].grades;
        theResults[i-1].grades = theResults[i].grades;
        theResults[i].grades = tempHold;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue I am having is that the `int` values (grades) are sorted correctly after the loop but having difficulty getting the names to be correctly allocated to match with the grades.

I have used the following code but it doesn't work as it displays the incorrect grades for the students.

```
char* title_temp = theResults[i-1].name;
theResults[i-1].name[20] = theResults[i].name[20];
theResults[i].name[20] = title_temp[20];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
if(theResults[i-1].grades < theResults[i].grades)
{
    int tempHold = theResults[i-1].grades;

    theResults[i-1].grades = theResults[i].grades;

    theResults[i].grades = tempHold;

    swapped = true;
}
```

What you really want to do is

```
if(theResults[i-1].grades < theResults[i].grades)
{
    Student tempHold = theResults[i-1];

    theResults[i-1] = theResults[i];

    theResults[i] = tempHold;

    swapped = true;
}
```

Before all you were changing was the grade value and not the names, this will switch the entire Student object and should produce the output you are looking for

Comment: Siegester, thank you. The code worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to swap the **objects**, the grades only have to act as a **key** to guide the sort, try this :

```
void bubble_sort(Student theResults[], int numCount)
{

    Student tempHold;
    bool swapped = true;
    while(swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for(int i=1;i<numCount;i++)
        {
            if(theResults[i-1].grades < theResults[i].grades)
            {
                tempHold = theResults[i-1]; //swap the objects, not just the grades.

                theResults[i-1]= theResults[i];

                theResults[i] = tempHold;

                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }}
```

However, if you must copy members, then in addition to swapping grades :

```
char temp[20];
strcpy(temp ,theResults[i-1].name);
strcpy(theResults[i-1].name,theResults[i].name);    
strcpy(theResults[i].name,temp);
```

Instead of using

```
    char* title_temp = theResults[i-1].name; // <-wrong
   theResults[i-1].name[20] = theResults[i].name[20];//20 is invalid index
    theResults[i].name[20] = title_temp[20]; //this is just 1 element out of the whole array
```

which is wrong due to **many** reasons.

Comment: axiom, excellent :D Also worked like a charm. Thank you for your help and advice. PS Sorry could only mark 1 as a correct answer and did the first post even though all three posts were correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to copy the entire char block, each element at a time using a loop, or you could use memcpy.

You could also use a shallow copy of your class

```
void bubble_sort(Student theResults[], int numCount)
{


    bool swapped = true;
    while(swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for(int i=1;i<numCount;i++)
        {
            if(theResults[i-1].grades < theResults[i].grades)
            {
                Student tempHold = theResults[i-1];

                theResults[i-1]= theResults[i];

                theResults[i] = tempHold;

                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nico, The above code also worked perfectly. Thank you for your time and help.PS Sorry could only mark 1 as a correct answer and I did the first post even though all three posts were correct. Sorry.